# How to configure the jboss server to read a client certificate

Tags: jboss, client-certificates

I have a PKCS12 keystore file. I have imported that in my browser. In my code I have to retrieve the certificate info and the data.

Is there any configuration needed to be done in JBOSS EAP 5.1?

```
    HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");    
    if (certs != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
    out.println("Client Certificate [" + i + "] = " + certs[i].toString());
    }
    }
    else {
    if ("https".equals(request.getScheme())) {
    out.println("This was an HTTPS request, but no client certificate is available");
    }
```

While running it. Line

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

giving null every time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the client is presenting the certificate?

It might not be exactly what you want to do but I did a similar thing in AS 7 using a security domain configured in standalone.xml

This thread pretty much explains it all:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/172052?start=0&tstart=0